# Quickest way to share file from shell

Tags: linux, ubuntu, shell

I'm using Ubuntu minimal install (With no window manager). 
What is the quickest and easiest way to upload a file somewhere? Something like a script to pastebin would work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ubuntu has a package called "pastebinit", which is a script that puts a file on pastebin and then prints the URL.

Install it with:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pastebinit
```

Using it is very easy:

```
$ pastebinit your_file.txt
http://pastebin.com/whatever
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this could help you:

[bash-script-to-post-on-pastebins](http://floyd-n-milan.blogspot.com/2006/11/bash-script-to-post-on-pastebins.html)